# PHP MySQL Website to External SQL System Integration

Tags: php, sql, mysql, integration

I am after opinions from some expert web developers as to the best solution to my problem.

THE SETUP

In my job, I look after an online shop, which is based upon osCommerce, with many additional features and tweaks. This is on Linux shared hosting and uses PHP and MySQL as its main technologies.

We are going through the process of upgrading our stock and order system, which is Microsoft SQL based and runs on a data server on our network (a Dell Server PC).

THE PROBLEM

I would like to achieve better integration between the stock/order system and our website, such as to get up-to-date stock information, check prices, etc. With the eventual aim of getting customer data linked as well.

MY POSSIBLE SOLUTION

I currently have XAMPP running on our SBS server for development, which I use to test new code, before uploading to the live site.

I have written a PHP file on this server, which connects to the SQL server and runs various SQL queries, taking in parameters in the $_GET array, retrieving the result as an associative array, JSON encoding the result and echoing the encoded string.

The website just uses something like this to get and use the result:

$result = file_get_contents('http://SBS-SERVER-IP/getinfo.php?partenquiry=' . $cleanStringPartNumber);

if ($result) $stock_info = (array) json_decode($result);

I thought this would be a decent solution as any logins for the SQL, even the fact that it is SQL is not exposed to the website, so if the website was compromised, it shouldn't compromise our system.

I will be making sure that the login for the SQL server only has access to SELECT data as I don't want to update/insert/delete anything as it may cause problems with the stock/order system.

Also, I was thinking of caching the results somewhere, so our stock/order system doesn't suffer performance issues.

I am sure there are many ways of passing the data between the 2 systems, but I want to be sure I am using a solution that is secure, using the most efficient and industry-standard methods of carrying this out.

I see technologies such as cURL, SOAP, XML, JSON, etc and wonder if any of these are ideal.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your current setup (or I'm sure that I don't ;-)). Your linux/osCommerce server right now is more or less a cache for the actual ordering system on your small business server? And you want a one-way synchronization sbs->linux server? At which point (in time or in the process) do you want your linux server to request data from the sbs?

Comment: Hi VolkerK, the 2 systems are separate. The SBS system is a Windows system for managing stock/orders; the sales team add orders that come in via e-mail, phone, fax, etc (mostly trade customers). The osCommerce site is mainly for retail customers. When orders come in on the site, a sales team member will add the order to our SBS system manually. Due to the nature of the business, all orders need to be checked over before being processed and put on the SBS system and some products we don't list on web. So I just want to request certain information from the SBS system and display it on the site.

Comment: I have a solution, outlined above, but as I just learn everything myself in PHP, I am always keen to know I am using more industry-accepted, secure and efficient methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use https if possible to have a secure communication between both servers.
Which technologie you use is up to you and the framework you are willing to learn.
JSON is one of the easiest way to send data from a to b.

SOAP practicly is XML but you don't have to bother with the XML itself.
Using SOAP you can send and store Objects.

Using php's serialize and unserialize you can transform objects too and send them and afterwards store the content of that object into the database.

It's more about preference and productionspeed.

Learning a new framework takes some time at first but can make you more productive afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ITroubs, I hadn't thought about https, but yes, I will make sure it communicates over https now. What are your thoughts about speed? I read that using cURL is quicker than the file_get_contents() function.